# remove bullet in ul for only few items

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a JSON similar to:

```
{
"qaset": [
    {
        "question": "question1",
        "answer": [
            "answer11",
            "answer12"
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "question2",
        "answer": "answer2"
    },
    {
        "question": "question1",
        "answer": [
            "answer31",
            "answer32"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have an accordion, that displays the question part above and when individually clicked opens up an answer. I am using ng-repeat to display the questions and the answers.

Now, the answers are ng-repeat on ul, li tags. Because of this, the questions that have only one answer are displayed against a bullet. How do I get rid of the bullet only for such single answer entries (i.e. answer2 above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li:only-child {
    list-style: none
}
```

Pure css.

**EDIT** Thanks @Michael Parker, you're right.
The pseudo-selector :only-child target element who is the only-child of his parent. While li targets all li, :only-child will restrict to all li who are only child of their parents.

Note than it will works for all only-child's li in **all** HTML. To restrict, use

```
.any-class li:only-child {
    list-style: none;
}
```

**EDIT** An example of implementation can be seen at http://cdpn.io/e/BzAxkZ

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks! 
   li:only-child {
        list-style: none;
    }
worked for me.
Only thing is, I had to still define "answer2" inside the an array i.e []. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  list-style: none;
}
```

would achieve what you're after. Here's a test case:

https://jsfiddle.net/bqeo6jx8/

Comment: The scenario I am working on is a little different than that mentioned in the test case above. Anyhow, @xXDarioXx has answered my question. Thanks anyway!